# Im trying to make a chrome extension to convert currencies automatically but i dont know how to get it to read a web page

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I'm in the process of developing a feature for a Chrome extension and could use some guidance. The core functionality I aim to implement is an automatic currency converter for web pages, specifically targeting e-commerce sites like eBay. The goal is to detect currency values within the page's HTML content, convert these values to a user-selected currency, and dynamically update the page with the converted values.

Question:
How can I detect the currency and pull that from the page to then put into my function to output the converted currency and input the answer to the the pages html?

If you're aware of any similar projects, code snippets, or tutorials, sharing those would be incredibly helpful.

I dont even really know where to start because I don't know what to search to begin.( as you can probably tell, I'm extreamly new to web development stuff)